# Import an image with Rails Admin Import to Active Storage from a URL provided in the CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import, rails-admin

*Rails 6.0.1 - Ruby 2.6.3 - Active Storage with rails_admin + rails_admin_import*

In my application, I'm using **Rails Admin** and **Rails Admin Import** to allow Admins to upload a CSV file with data into my model.

In the model, I have a coverphoto attachment setup for active storage.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
has_one_attached :coverphoto
end


----------
```

I manage to upload images to each record manually via Rails Admin, but when I try to upload a CSV file with a coverphoto column, its throwing the following error:

```
Error during import: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (/Users/../.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:176:in `verify')
```

All other fields that have a corresponding attribute in my model I can upload if I delete the coverphoto column, but I can't figure out how to upload the image.

---

The documentation for Rails Admin Import includes this for CarrierWave but I can't figure out how I should modify it to make it work with **Active Storage Uploads**.

```
#Import an image into Carrierwave via a URL provided in the CSV.
def before_import_save(record)
  self.remote_image_url = record[:image] if record[:image].present?  
end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You are mixing Rails Admin and Active Admin on your question, would you mind clarifying which gem are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm using Rails Admin. Updated the question now.
gem 'rails_admin', git: 'https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
gem "rails_admin_import", "~> 2.2"

Answer (score 0):

Try on your rails console assigning a url to that field

```
post = Post.last
post.coverphoto = 'https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'
post.save
```

It will probably fail with the same error. But if you do this first

```
post = Post.last
post.coverphoto = URI.parse('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff')
post.save
```

It should work.

So do the same on the before_import_saved method.